# Using SUMPRODUCT, but exclude return if criteria cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large array. In column A there are discreet numbers, 1,2,3 etc. Those numbers are then used in the array (e through gf) to register the person who has been assigned the number from column A to as many items as they register in the array.

What I want in column C is how many times that registration number (from column A) appears in the array, so I have a count of their total item registrations.

I used this formula (found on this forum): =SUMPRODUCT ((e3:gh199="cell")*1) where "cell" is the cell reference from column A that I'm looking for in the array (the discreet number). The problem is that I need to account for more entries than I will have, so there will be blank cells in column A, but the formula then returns the number of blank cells in the array. So I need to add the correct instruction that if the cell criteria in A is blank, not to return any value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `COUNTIF`? For example if "cell" is A1

`=COUNTIF(E$3:GH$199,A1)`

If A1 is blank that will return zero even if there are blanks in `E3:GH199`

If you want to return a blank if A1 is blank just add an IF function like this:

`=IF(A1="","",COUNTIF(E$3:GH$199,A1))`